Controlling when a wrap occurs in a flexbox
I have a two column page, one skinny column and one fat column. I am using a flexbox to display them.
When I resize the browser width smaller, the wider div wraps almost immediately. I expected it to gradually shrink in width prior to wrapping.
This is the code I have developed for this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flexbox Test</title>
  <style>
    #container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    }
    
    #narrow-text {
      flex-grow: 10;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      flex-basis: 15rem;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    #wide-text {
      flex-grow: 10;
      flex-shrink: 10;
      flex-basis: 56rem;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="narrow-text">
      <br>
      <h3>NARROW TEXT</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="wide-text">
      <br>
      <h3>WIDE TEXT</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for your reply Paulie_D. Apologies for not being clear. The code above produces two columns of text. One narrow and one wide. When the browser width is decreased slowly, the wide-text div almost immediately wraps above the narrow-text div. What I would like to see is the wide-text div gradually shrink as the browser width is reduced until a certain point when it wraps above the narrow-text div. Does that make any more sense?

You can use min-width to ensure that the flex boxes can shrink till a certain point and then they will wrap. Also i have use percentages in flex-basis instead of rem because it is more easier to understand/visualize how the boxes will behave.
I have kept the flex-grow and flex-shrink to 1. This will make sure that the boxes will grow when wrapped and shrink when browser is minimised. Please update the flex-shrink if you need to change the proportion of shrinking.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flexbox Test</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
        }
     
        
        #narrow-text {   
           flex: 1 1 30%; /* Box can grow and shrink */
           min-width: 150px; /* Minimum width before wrapping */
        }

        #wide-text {
          flex: 1 1 70%; /* Box can grow and shrink */
          min-width: 350px; /* Minimum width before wrapping */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="narrow-text" class="flex-item">
            <br>
            <h3>NARROW TEXT</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="wide-text" class="flex-item">
            <br>
            <h3>WIDE TEXT</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>       

</body>

</html>




Thank you @Codemaster - thats exactly what I wanted. Cheers.
